# Stuck on ionic install - Windows 10 x64

Tags: node.js, cordova, ionic-framework, npm, ionic2

I'm trying (for many hours) to install [ionic framework](https://ionicframework.com/) on my Windows 10 x64 laptop. I have already installed [cordova](https://cordova.apache.org/). I did the following steps:

Downloaded and installed NodeJS 6.9.4 for x64 Windows system, unistalled cordova doing: `npm uninstall -g cordova`.
Then install cordova `npm install -g cordova`.

And finally `npm install -g ionic` and it got stucks, here is the log...

```
C:\Users\MYUSERNAME>npm install -g ionic -verbose
npm info it worked if it ends with ok
npm verb cli [ 'C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe',
npm verb cli   'C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js',
npm verb cli   'install',
npm verb cli   '-g',
npm verb cli   'ionic',
npm verb cli   '-verbose' ]
npm info using npm@3.10.10
npm info using node@v6.9.4
npm verb request uri http://registry.npmjs.org/ionic
npm verb request no auth needed
npm info attempt registry request try #1 at 12:46:00
npm verb request id 16a4444c294114d9
npm verb etag W/"58791579-d1a5a"
npm verb lastModified Fri, 13 Jan 2017 17:59:21 GMT
npm http request GET http://registry.npmjs.org/ionic
npm http 304 http://registry.npmjs.org/ionic
npm verb headers { date: 'Sun, 15 Jan 2017 16:46:01 GMT',
npm verb headers   via: '1.1 varnish',
npm verb headers   'cache-control': 'max-age=300',
npm verb headers   etag: 'W/"58791579-d1a5a"',
npm verb headers   age: '102',
npm verb headers   connection: 'keep-alive',
npm verb headers   'x-served-by': 'cache-dfw1827-DFW',
npm verb headers   'x-cache': 'HIT',
npm verb headers   'x-cache-hits': '1',
npm verb headers   'x-timer': 'S1484498761.499022,VS0,VE2',
npm verb headers   vary: 'Accept-Encoding' }
npm verb etag http://registry.npmjs.org/ionic from cache
npm verb get saving ionic to C:\Users\MYUSERNAME\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\registry.npmjs.org\ionic\.cache.json
npm verb correctMkdir C:\Users\MYUSERNAME\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache correctMkdir not in flight; initializing
npm verb cache add spec ionic
npm verb addNamed "latest" is being treated as a dist-tag for ionic
npm info addNameTag [ 'ionic', 'latest' ]
npm verb addNameTag registry:http://registry.npmjs.org/ionic not in flight; fetching
npm verb get http://registry.npmjs.org/ionic not expired, no request
npm verb addNamed "2.2.1" is a plain semver version for ionic
npm verb addRemoteTarball http://registry.npmjs.org/ionic/-/ionic-2.2.1.tgz not in flight; adding
npm verb addRemoteTarball [ 'http://registry.npmjs.org/ionic/-/ionic-2.2.1.tgz',
npm verb addRemoteTarball   '2b9d90b3ae109138084473282c18ea162a5f8248' ]
npm info retry fetch attempt 1 at 12:46:01
npm info attempt registry request try #1 at 12:46:01
npm http fetch GET http://registry.npmjs.org/ionic/-/ionic-2.2.1.tgz
npm http fetch 200 http://registry.npmjs.org/ionic/-/ionic-2.2.1.tgz
[    ..............] | loadRequestedDeps: http fetch 200 http://registry.npmjs.org/ionic/-/ionic-2.2.1.tgz
```

I have cleaned the cache on npm, I tried to install ionic from `yarn`, it seems to be installed but I can't use it... I think I need install ionic via npm.

```
npm version: 3.10.10
node version: v6.9.4
javac version: javac 1.8.0_74
```

How the hell can I finish the install of ionic framework. Thanks for reading, and please forgive my way to write english.

Comment: can I install `http://registry.npmjs.org/ionic/-/ionic-2.2.1.tgz` manually in order to complete the installation?

Comment: I realize that I must wait around 3 hours to complete the ionic installation... Why? My internet connection is normal, I don't use VPN's or proxies... Why this happens?

Comment: I have the same issue, it is f...ing pretty weird, because I managed to install ionic cordova last year, but ionic v 2.1.8 (I think) and right now trying to install the final v2 but I can't, it stucks in loadRequestedDeps, it is pretty annoying.